# How can I set new values in a range list, from the sums in another range list?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-api, setvalue

Please excuse my limited knowledge in advance.

In Google Sheets, I have a budget column (K) that sums multiple inputs and displays the most recent totals.

I am trying to create a script that will copy select values from column K and set those values into column I upon execution.

Both column K and I have sum totals in various rows throughout so a simple copy and pasting of the entire column would overwrite those functions. This will be a repeatable action to set new values once they are calculated into this column so I plan to assign it to a button.

I'm using User [Tanaike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) wonderful RangeListApp to help reference the multiple ranges I'm referencing.

The first half of the code seems to be working:

```
function UpdateEFC() {
  var rangeList = ['K4:K6', 'K9:K14', 'K17:K18', 'K21:K24', 'K27', 'K30:K38', 'K41:K49', 'K52:K53', 'K56:K60', 'K63:K67', 'K70:K72', 'K75:K76', 'K79:K85', 'K88:K92', 'K95:K106', 'K109:K114', 'K117:K126', 'K129:K133', 'K136:K147', 'K150:K153', 'K156:K163', 'K166:K167', 'K170:K174', 'K177', 'K180:K182', 'K185', 'K188:K190', 'K193', 'K196:K205', 'K208:K214', 'K217'];
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = RangeListApp.getSpreadsheet(spreadsheet).getRangeList(rangeList).getDisplayValues();
```

Again, each range listed (i.e. "k4:k6") are sum functions in each cell. When I log this script it returns the calculated value in each cell. Here is an example from the log:

```
[{range='CR Template'!K4:K6, values=[[ $ 28,000.00 ], [ $ 25,000.00 ], [ $ 27,500.00 ]]},
```

When I attempt to set these values into column I, however, I run into issues.

I have tried the following:

```
var destinationList = ["I4:I6", "I9:I14", "I17:I18", "I21:I24", "I27", "I30:I38", "I41:I49", "I52:I53", "I56:I60", "I63:I67", "I70:I72", "I75:I76", "I79:I85", "I88:I92", "I95:I106", "I109:I114", "I117:I126", "I129:I133", "I136:I147", "I150:I153", "I156:I163", "I166:I167", "I170:I174", "I177", "I180:I182", "I185", "I188:I190", "I193", "I196:I205", "I208:I214", "I217"];
var values = rangeList;
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
RangeListApp.getSpreadsheet(spreadsheet).getRangeList(destinationList).setValues(values);
```

This script returns the cell ranges into column as written in the script. i.e. I4 = K4:K6, I5 = K4:K6, I6 = K4:K6 but does not return the displayed numerical summed value.

I have also tried a version where

```
var values = r;
```

My thinking was to take the output of displayed values and set those values into the new range list, however this only returned:

```
[object Object]
```

into each cell.

I know I have something wrong here in how to define or recall the values so any guidance here would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from `['K4:K6', 'K9:K14', 'K17:K18',,,]` to `["I4:I6", "I9:I14", "I17:I18",,,]`.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, [my RangeListApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RangeListApp) cannot copy the values with the ranges. So, in this case, as a current workaround, I would like to propose using a script with Sheets API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?hl=ja#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // These ranges are from your script.
  var srcRangeList = ['K4:K6', 'K9:K14', 'K17:K18', 'K21:K24', 'K27', 'K30:K38', 'K41:K49', 'K52:K53', 'K56:K60', 'K63:K67', 'K70:K72', 'K75:K76', 'K79:K85', 'K88:K92', 'K95:K106', 'K109:K114', 'K117:K126', 'K129:K133', 'K136:K147', 'K150:K153', 'K156:K163', 'K166:K167', 'K170:K174', 'K177', 'K180:K182', 'K185', 'K188:K190', 'K193', 'K196:K205', 'K208:K214', 'K217'];
  var dstRangeList = ["I4:I6", "I9:I14", "I17:I18", "I21:I24", "I27", "I30:I38", "I41:I49", "I52:I53", "I56:I60", "I63:I67", "I70:I72", "I75:I76", "I79:I85", "I88:I92", "I95:I106", "I109:I114", "I117:I126", "I129:I133", "I136:I147", "I150:I153", "I156:I163", "I166:I167", "I170:I174", "I177", "I180:I182", "I185", "I188:I190", "I193", "I196:I205", "I208:I214", "I217"];

  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: srcRangeList.map(e => `'${sheetName}'!${e}`), valueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE" }).valueRanges;
  var data = values.map(({ values }, i) => ({ range: `'${sheetName}'!${dstRangeList[i]}`, values }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of `srcRangeList` is copied to `dstRangeList`.

#### Note:

- I would like to consider updating [RangeListApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RangeListApp).

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: @Mark McCune About `This worked! thank you.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I added the following to allow for the shedName to be dynamic based on which one is active var sheetName = (function getSheetName() {
  let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  return activeSheet.getName();})();

Comment: @Mark McCune Thank you for your response. I understood it.